# Scaling radio button location with form size change

Tags: c#, winforms, radio-button

The quick rundown of the app that im making is basically a geography game where you need to click on a radio button that represents a capital city.I added a map to the background and made it scale with form size.The issue comes when I resize the form the radio buttons stay in place.

```
private void resizeControl(Rectangle r, Control c)
{
    float xRatio = (float)(this.Width) / (float)(originalFormSize.Width);
    float yRatio = (float)(this.Height) / (float)(originalFormSize.Height);

    int newX = (int)(r.Width * xRatio);
    int newY = (int)(r.Height * yRatio);

    int newWidth = (int)(r.Width * xRatio);
    int newHeight = (int)(r.Height * yRatio);

    c.Location = new Point(newX, newY);
    c.Size = new Size(newWidth, newHeight);
}
```

I tried using the code above but it didn't work I also tried

```
btn.Location.X=btn.Location.X+(newFormSize.Width-oldFormSize.Width);
```

but both of these code send the button into -x and -y for some reason.

Comment: Do not put controls directly into a form.  Add a Panel to the Form and add all your controls into the Panel. The Panel will take care of resizing so you do not have to deal with issue.

Comment: The background picture is already in a panel the buttons are on top of it, I tried it in a nother app but doesent work. Is there a setting that i need to enable in the panel or?

Comment: Are the buttons in the panel or in the form?  Make sure the button are in the panel.

Comment: If you have place the RadioButton inside a container at design-time, you have to consider - and store - the original locations of these Controls, then use the Ratio you have calculated and multiply the original X and Y position by this Ratio. NOT keep on adding to an already moved Location. otherwise the new Location will always increase or decrease (based on the scale method you have defined) and never return to the original position

Comment: It would be better to define the positions, in pixels, inside the Bitmap(s) and position the Controls using this *map*. Scale these positions as the Bitmap scales. It makes to easier to position the Controls in case you have multiple maps that may be already scaled when first added to the container used to show them